# VB to java problems

Tags: java, vb.net

I have VB code and want to convert it to Java for a mobile app, but I always get a different end result in Java and I don't know where my mistake is, or what I'm doing wrong.

**VB Code:**

```vb
Private Function PasswortlevelHash(ByVal Passworltevel As String, ByVal 

    Tag As String, ByVal Monat As String, ByVal Jahr As String) As String
    Dim uEncode As New UnicodeEncoding
    Dim md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    
    Dim strForHash As String = "MS-U4_2022_10_10setup"
    Dim bytHashNeu() As Byte = uEncode.GetBytes(strForHash)
    Dim strHash1 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(bytHashNeu))
    PasswortlevelHash = strHash1

End Function
```

**Result: h1qKTNN456AqTZUPPaft3Q==**

**Java:**

```java
private String PasswortlevelHash(String strPasswortlevel, String strDay, String strMonth, String strYear) throws Exception {

    MD5 md5 = new MD5();
    
    String strForHash = "MS-U4_2022_10_10setup"
    byte[] bytHash = strForHash.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] bytBOM = {(byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xBF };
    byte[] bytGesamt =  addAll(bytBOM, bytHash);
    
    String strHash = getMD5(bytGesamt);
    String strHash2 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(strHash.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    
    return strHash2 ;
}
```

**Result: NDM5MjFmZjJiMjc1YjRlZTI0YmQ4NGI0YTQ2ZjQxMTI=**

Comment: What does `getMD5` do, and why does it return a string instead of a byte array? Also, the fact you do `MD5 md5 = new MD5();` in your method and then never do anything with it, but call instance or static methods to - presumably - update the MD5 message-digest or equivalent, suggests that you may be generating an MD5 with a message digest that already has previous data.

Comment: Also given, the Java base64 output decoded is the string `43921ff2b275b4ee24bd84b4a46f4112`, suggests that `getMD5` returns the MD5 encoded using hexadecimals, which means you should decode that hex string to bytes (instead of using `getBytes`), before encoding with base64.

Comment: In any case, you really need to provide a [mre] of your Java code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET [UnicodeEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.unicodeencoding?view=net-6.0) class handles UTF-16:

> Represents a UTF-16 encoding of Unicode characters.

But you used UTF-8 in the Java code.

**UPDATE**

As Mark pointed out, you also have an extra hex conversion. Here is a working Java code:

```java
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Test
{
    public static String getHash(String s) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] md5 = md.digest(s.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(md5);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        System.out.println(getHash("MS-U4_2022_10_10setup"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
h1qKTNN456AwTZUPPaft3Q==
```

Comment: This is likely part 1 of the problem, part 2 is that `getMD5()` returns a hex-encoded string, a potential part 3 is that it seems the MD5 message digest or equivalent might have previous initialization data.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You're totally right. I updated my answer.